# Logstash and logstash-forwarder ssl error

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I have 2 servers:

- logstash server
- app server

If I run a logstash-forwarder on a logstash server - it's ok.

But if I run logstash-forwarder on app server i get an error:

```
Failed to tls handshake with <ip> x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

And when I check the certificate by command:

```
openssl x509 -in logstash-forwarder.crt -noout -text
```

I take a valid certificate:

```
        ...
        Validity
        Not Before: Jun 28 17:33:36 2015 GMT
        Not After : Jun 27 17:33:36 2016 GMT
        ...
        X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
            IP Address:<ip>
```

Date on app serve:

```
root@app:/etc/pki/logstash# date
Sun Jun 28 20:53:30 MSK 2015
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar kind of issue and fixed it. Looks like you didn't have any DNS set for you logstash index server. In this case you have to set SAN to `openssl.cnf` and regenerate the cert along with key.

How to set SAN?

```
sudo vi /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
```

Find the *[ v3_ca ]* section in the file, and add this line under it (substituting in the Logstash Index Server's IP address):

```
subjectAltName = IP: logstash__index_server_private_ip
```

After that try regenerating your cert and key

```
cd /etc/pki/tls
sudo openssl req -config /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf -x509 -days 3650 -batch -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private/logstash-forwarder.key -out certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
```

And change your config file to point the cert and key from both end(index and forwarder) accordingly. Hope this will workout for you.